# Seeking shell-scripting resources for the visual learner

Tags: macos, terminal, script, command-line

I'm trying to teach myself shell scripting. I understand things best when I see them in the context of a system, especially when I can visualize that system. I'm looking for a visual companion to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/DOCUMENTATION/OpenSource/Conceptual/ShellScripting/Introduction/Introduction.html). Obviously I'm going to have to do a lot of reading to learn this stuff, and also lots of trial and error with the Terminal. But I'd love the help of visual aids. **Are there any good resources for shell-scripting Mac OS X that have drawings, diagrams, and/or illustrations?**

Answer (score 1):

Here's [a site that helped](http://blog.flowblok.id.au/2013-02/shell-startup-scripts.html), and one of its diagrams:[image: images]
<sub>(source: [flowblok.id.au](http://blog.flowblok.id.au/static/images/shell-startup.png))</sub>  .